# Debian assemble MIPS natively

Tags: assembly, debian, mips

I want to learn some basic MIPS assembly. I have a MIPS virtual machine running Debian so I would like to use it. I want to use the mips assembly and not the GNU portable assembly language.

Which assembler do I need to install? What commands should I issue to assemble the code? Is there a tutorial that explains the whole process?

I'm sorry if somebody else has already asked this but I wasn't able to find the answer to my question.

Comment: There are plenty of good mips simulators which are much easier to learn with. Look up `spim` or `MARS`

Comment: Why would I want to use a simulator? I want to assemble and run a program the same way as I would compile and run it if it was written in C.

Comment: Don't Linux distros usually come with gcc and binutils installed?  If so you should be able to use `gcc` on your virtual MIPS machine to compile your assembly code, or use `as` and `ld` directly to assemble and link. As for how to use the tools, google for _"mips assembly gnu"_.

Comment: @martinkunev I understand the objection. The suggestion is based solely on the fact that you asked to `learn some basic MIPS assembly`. Using a simulator is a much easier way to learn the basics than any other approach.